# Re-sizing Partition to install Windows alongside Ubuntu

Tags: windows, system-installation, gparted

I installed Ubuntu in my hard drive without making any separate partitions. Now I would also like to install Windows 8 but I'm unable to re-size using gParted. How can separate free space on my hard disk and install windows.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. It will be great if you can provide few more information such as a screen shot of the gParted partition table.. etc. Also, you may need to repair the GRUB once you've installed Windows as the bootloader of windows will boot over Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Run Gparted from Ubuntu Live CD, because you can't edit partition that you are currently using.